# Symmetric functions for multidimensional variables

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials

I have $N$ variables (let's call them  $X$) of dimensionality $D$, that I want to make permutation invariant.

For $D=1$ I know I can use e.g. the elementary symmetric polynomials to accomplish this. What if $D>1$ (only integer dimensions, not fractals :) and $\bar{X}$ are vectors? Is there a way to systematically generate functions which are symmetric under permutations of their variables ( i.e. $f_i(\bar{X}_i, \bar{X}_j)$ = $f_i(\bar{X}_j, \bar{X}_i)$), $f_1, f_2, ..., f_N$ so that $f_i(\bar{X}_1, ..., \bar{X}_N)$ generates a vector of dimension $D$?

If this is not possible in general, can we accomplish it for the limited case when $N=2$ and $D>1$?

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not really telling us what operations you want your object to be symmetric under. Once you're clear about this, you can always pick an arbitrary representative and sum over the equivalence class. That's by construction symmetric.

Comment: right, symmetric under permutations of $\bar{X}_i$. Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the question

Comment: Basically you are asking about the coordinate ring of $((\Bbbk^D)^{\otimes N})/S_N$, I think?

Comment: If it is Zach's interpretation which is meant in the post then the relevant search term is the theory of "multisymmetric functions". It is a very difficult subject. Good luck.

Comment: One obvious construction is $f_i (\bar{X}_{1},\ldots,\bar{X}_{N} ) = \sum_{P} g_i (\bar{X}_{P(1)},\ldots,\bar{X}_{P(N)} )$ where $P$ denote all the permutations of $N$ objects, and $g_i $ can be anything you like. If $g_i $ is a bona fide tensor, $f_i $ will inherit that property - that aspect is independent of the symmetrization issue.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I appreciate the solution may be very complicated or computationally expensive now.